# Пишу змейку, она должна управляться с клавиатуры, но написанный мною listener почему-то не запускается. Я куда-то не туда его добавляю?

Tags: java, многопоточность, intellij-idea, разработка-игр, listener

Пробовала добавлять в Window, Snake и создаваемый в последнем JFrame, результата никакого, при нажатии кнопок lisener даже не запускается(проверено при помощи попыток вывести символы и пошаговой отладки). У меня есть предположение, что это может быть связано с использованием потока как таймера.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Window window = new Window();
        System.out.print("k");
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Window  extends JPanel {
    private Snake snake; 


    public Window() {
        super(true);
        snake = Snake.getSnake(50, 50);
        Thread snakeThread = new Thread(snake);
        snakeThread.start();
     

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        snake.paint(g);
    }
}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Snake extends JPanel implements Runnable {

    public static int length;
    public static ArrayList<Point> parts;
    public static Field field;
    public static Food food;
    public static int speedX=0;
    public static int speedY=1;

private static Snake snake = null;

    public static final int TIME_DELTA = 1000;
public static  Snake getSnake(int w, int h)
{
    if(snake == null) {
        snake = new Snake(w, h);
        snake.addKeyListener(new Turn(snake));
    }
    return snake;
}

    private Snake(int Width, int Heigth) {

        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        jf.add(this); //this - это Jpanel которым расширяется Snake
        jf.setVisible(true);


        food = new Food();field = Field.getField();
        Point start = new Point((int)Width/2, (int)Heigth/2); //размеры поля, а не окна
        parts = new ArrayList<>();parts.add(start);
        Point p1 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)start.getY())-1);parts.add(p1);
        Point p2 = new Point((int)start.getX(), ((int)p1.getY())-1);
        parts.add(p2);length = 3;
    }
  

    private boolean checkHead()
    {
        for (int i=1; i<parts.size(); ++i)
        {
            if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getLocation() == parts.get(i).getLocation())
                return false;
        }

        if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() <=0 || parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() >= field.sizeX ||
                parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY() <=0 || parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY() >= field.sizeY )
            return false;

        return true;
    }

    public static void move()
    {
        for (Point i: parts)
        {
            i.y=i.y-1*speedY;
            i.x-=1*speedX;
        }
    }
    public static void eat()
    {
        Point np = new Point ((int)parts.get(length).getX(),(int)parts.get(length).getY()-1 );
        parts.add(np);
        ++length;
        food.respawn();
    }

    public static boolean checkFood()
    {
        if(parts.get(parts.size()-1).getX() == food.x &&  parts.get(parts.size()-1).getY()==food.y)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

  
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        for (Point i: parts) 
            g.fillRect((int) i.getX() * 10, (int) i.getY() * 10, 8, 8);

       g.setColor(Color.RED);
       g.fillRect(food.x * 10, food.y * 10, 8, 8);
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    @Override

            public void run() {
        while (checkHead()) {
            move();
            repaint();
            if(checkFood())
                eat();
            try {
                Thread.sleep(TIME_DELTA);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
            }

            public  void turn(char Key)
            {
                int delta = 0;
                for(Point i: parts)
                {
                    switch (Key) {
                        case 'a':
                            i.y=parts.get(parts.size()-1).y;
                            i.x=parts.get(parts.size()-1).x+delta;
                            break;
                        case'd':
                            i.y=parts.get(parts.size()-1).y;
                            i.x=parts.get(parts.size()-1).x-delta;
                            break;

                        case 'w':
                            i.x=parts.get(parts.size()-1).x;
                            i.y=parts.get(parts.size()-1).y-delta;
                            break;
                        case's':
                            i.x=parts.get(parts.size()-1).x;
                            i.y=parts.get(parts.size()-1).y+delta;
                            break;
                    }
                    ++delta;
                }
                repaint();
            }


}
```

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class Food extends JPanel {
    public static  int x;
    public static int y;
    private static Random random;

    public Food()
    {
        super(true);
        random = new Random();
        
       x =  random.nextInt(50);
       y = random.nextInt(50);
    }

    @Override
   public void paint(Graphics g) {
        super.paint(g);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.fillRect(x * 10, y * 10, 8, 8);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    }

    public  void respawn()
    {
        x = random.nextInt(40);
        y = random.nextInt(40);
        repaint();
    }
}
```

Сам listener:

```
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyListener;


public class Turn implements KeyListener {
   private char key = 'O';
   private Snake snake;

   public Turn(Snake s)
   {
       this.snake = s;
   }


    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("0");
        if(e.getKeyChar() == 'A')
        {
            System.out.println("a");
            if(snake.speedX==0)
            {
                snake.speedX=-1;
                snake.speedY=0;
                key='a';
            }
        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'W')
        {
            System.out.println("w");
            if(snake.speedY==0)
            {
                snake.speedY=-1;
                snake.speedX=0;
                key='w';
            }

        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'S')
        {
            System.out.println("s");
            if(snake.speedY==0)
            {
                snake.speedY=1;
                snake.speedX=0;
                key='s';
            }

        }
        else if (e.getKeyChar() == 'D')
        {
            System.out.println("d");
            if(snake.speedX==0)
            {
                snake.speedX=1;
                snake.speedY=0;
                key='d';
            }
        }
        if(key!='O')
snake.turn(key);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Разбирая ваш пример, логичнее всего KeyListner повесить прямо на фрейм.

*Забегая вперед, скажу что пытаясь поймать `e.getKeyChar() == 'D'` система будет ждать именно большую букву D*

У вас есть класс Snake, вот там в конструкторе мы это и сделаем. Мне кажется кидать листнер в методе getSnake не очень хорошо, так что лучше удалите это  `snake.addKeyListener(new Turn(snake));`

В Snake, предварительно изменив класс Turn :

Класс Turn - конструктор

```
public class Turn implements KeyListener{
    private char key = 'O';
    // Старайтесь не использовать волшебные знаки/числа
    // Описывайте их в полях класса
    private char keyA = 'a';
    private char keyW = 'w';
    private char keyD = 'd';
    private char keyS = 's';
    
    

    private Snake snake;

    public Turn(Snake s, JFrame jFrame)
    {
        this.snake = s;
        jFrame.addKeyListener(this);
        // Мы как бы говорим фрейму, эй дружище, я хочу чтобы ты
        // Обрабатывал переопределенные методы кей-хука именно в этом классе.

    }
   // Ваш код далее...
```

Класс Snake - Конструктор

```
public Snake(int Width, int Heigth) {
        // Делаем конструктор публичным
        // Добавляем Jframe
        JFrame jf = new JFrame();
        jf.setSize(500,500);
        jf.add(this); //this - это Jpanel которым расширяется Snake
        jf.setVisible(true);

        new Turn(this,jf);
        // add Listner
        // this - Snake + Jpanel
        // jf   - Jrame
        // Ваш код далее...
```

Запустил, сразу скажу двигается не так, как надо, и не всегда туда, куда нужно ) Но с этим я думаю вы справитесь.